# I deactivated zeitgeist and need help reactivating it

Tags: 14.04, sudo, zeitgeist, startupmanager

All I have been able to do is to activate it in the startup programs, but not in the privacy settings, it looks different now.
I also run from a terminal:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-ft
```

during deactivation, how can undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed the executable rights with `-x`.

**Here is your *undo*:**

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-ft
```

---

These are the settings in my system:

```
% ls -la /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 214216 Mär 10 17:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
% ls -la /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub     
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131696 Mär 10 17:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub
```

---

**Or reinstall the packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zeitgeist-datahub
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zeitgeist-core
```

<sub>I can't find [/usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-ft](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=zeitgeist-ft&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) for Ubuntu</sub>

Comment: thanks I had to reinstall zeitgeist, the other option could not run cause I was missing a file.